# Linq Query, Where Contains

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT     xObjectID, xObjectName
FROM         dbo.xObject
where  CONTAINS( xObjectRef, '1838 AND 238671')
```

Which i am trying to convert to linq but i can't get it to work,
And it's driving me up the wall.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulltext searches are not compatible with linq to sql. You will have to call a stored procedure.

Edit:

Or do you want a linq query that will return the same result set as the sql?

Comment: I have only just learned that it was indeed a full text search query.
Is it possible to get the same results in linq (with around the same performance?)

Comment: Depends really. How many rows are there in dbo.xObject table?? If there are not that much then using linq (which will generate a sql 'LIKE' command) should be ok.

Comment: Nope there are thousands. I have changed to a stored procedure.
Now looking into how i can get the results into another data class.

I used to have select new FlValue() But that doesn't work with stored procedures it seems.

Comment: Also what is the type of xObjectRef column? What is its length?

Comment: It's ntext and the content length is 256 characters

Comment: ntext? Wow. I think sticking to full text searches with stored procedure is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? This does require `xObjectRef` to be a property of `xObject`.

```
from obj in dbo.xObject
where obj.xObjectRef.Contains("1838") && obj.xObjectRef.Contains("238671")
select new { xObjectId = obj.xObjectId, xObjectName = obj.xObjectName}
```

Comment: Ofcourse you're right. Miscommunication in my head somewhere.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from c in context.xObject 
             where c.xObjectRef.Contains("1838") && c.xObjectRef.Contains("238671")
             select new { ObjectID = c.xObjectID, ObjectName = c.xObjectName };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var  a = xObject.where(n=>n.Contains("1838") && n.Contains("238671") )).
                    Select(s=>new {xObjectID=s.xObjectID , xObjectName=s.xObjectName});
```